# Facebook iOS SDK 3.0 - session not open

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook

I am using the latest Facebook iOS SDK 3.0

I need a help in in the login process:

First I declare this property in `AppDelegate.h`:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) FBSession *session;
```

and in ViewController class I get this to use it in the code as this:

```
AppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
[delegate.session someproperty];
```

I also have this method in ViewController that get called from `viewDidLoad`:

```
-(void)login
{
    AppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    [delegate.session accessToken];
    NSLog(@"%d",delegate.session.isOpen);
    if (!delegate.session.isOpen)
    {
        delegate.session = [[FBSession alloc] init];
        if (delegate.session.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded)
        {
            [delegate.session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                      FBSessionState status,
                                                      NSError *error) 
            {
              NSLog(@"%d", delegate.session.isOpen); // First Line //////////////////
            }];
        }
        NSLog(@"%@", delegate.session.description);   // Second Line //////////////////
    }
 }
```

After the facebook app get authorized the firs `NSLog` print zero, and the second `NSLog` indicate that the `session` state is `FBSessionStateCreated` not `FBSessionStateOpen`?

this is the output for the second `NSLog`:

```
2012-08-16 18:37:24.327 Facebook3[2418:f803] <FBSession: 0x6890ff0, state:    FBSessionStateCreated, loginHandler: 0x0, appID: 193716877424306, urlSchemeSuffix: , tokenCachingStrategy:<FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy: 0x6890f20>, expirationDate: (null), refreshDate: (null), attemptedRefreshDate: 0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:()>
```

What I am missing here.

Note : in the app setting at https://developers.facebook.com I configure the app as this:
1- Configured for iOS SSO: Enabled
2- iOS Native Deep Linking: Enabled
3- iOS Bundle ID : com.mycompany.appname

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i used this framework for my project. it works properly. 
this is my related code

```
   -(IBAction)logIn:(id)sender;
{
    AppDelegate *appdelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if (!FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
        [appdelegate sessionOpener];
    }
    else {
        [self loginHelp];
    }
```

and my sessionOpener function is;

```
    -(void) sessionOpener
{

    [FBSession sessionOpenWithPermissions:nil
                        completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                            FBSessionState status,
                                            NSError *error) {
                            // session might now be open.
                            if (!error) {
                                [self.viewController loginHelp];
                            }
                        }];

     NSLog(@"%d", FBSession.activeSession.isOpen);
    NSLog(@"%@", FBSession.activeSession.description );
}
```

it works for me. may be helpful to you.

and my console print is:

```
     1
2012-08-16 22:24:55.899 TaraftarlikOyunu[838:c07] <FBSession: 0xd2512c0, state: FBSessionStateOpen, loginHandler: 0xd250240, appID: 433294056715040, urlSchemeSuffix: , tokenCachingStrategy:<FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy: 0xd24fda0>, expirationDate: 2012-10-15 19:02:34 +0000, refreshDate: 2012-08-16 19:05:03 +0000, attemptedRefreshDate: 0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:(
    )>
```

Comment: thnx for your answer I will try it ,,, but is the different between using `FBSession` and instance of `FBSession` class?

Comment: have you got a - (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session
                      state:(FBSessionState) state
                      error:(NSError *)error

Comment: Yes I have one in the `ViewController` class but it never get called, do you know why?

Comment: it should be in the appdelegate. because you define the session in appdelegate.

Comment: ok. did you make request. can you get any information about session.

Comment: I don't know what do you mean with request, my current session state is `FBSessionStateOpen` ,,, note that these operation done in `ViewController`

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding. i am checking whether the session is opened or not with NSLog(@"%d", FBSession.activeSession.isOpen); it prints 1.

Comment: i guess after creating the session it makes the session active. and you can check it with this code. i edited my code

Comment: @meth can u take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414118/how-to-close-active-session-of-facebook-ios-sdk

Comment: Is this answer outdated? There seems to be no such method now.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as you and I had mixed between using FBSession and instance of FBSession when calling handleOpenURL. I changed from

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
     annotation:(id)annotation {
    [FBSession.activeSession facebookSession handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

to this

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
     annotation:(id)annotation {
    [session facebookSession handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

Comment: [session facebookSession handleOpenURL:url] is syntactically not correct.